# how to uninstall .net framework 4.8 from windows 10

Tags: .net, frameworks, windows-10

I have windows 10 and .net framework 4.7.2 installed and my program works fine. Then I figured to try the .net framework 4.8, after installation, my program doesn't work. I was trying to uninstall .net framework 4.8, I did the uninstall from control panel, but the registry HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full is permanently set at version 4.8.03761. I've searched online for hours on how to completely rid of this 4.8 version to no avail. I also read that Microsoft made the decision that 4.8 version update to be irreversible, I am hoping this is not true and hope for ways that I can go back to 4.7.2 version without completely nuking the whole system and starting over.

Comment: When you say your program doesn't work, how does this manifest? Is the source code under your control? Depending on the nature of the problem, you might have an easier time modifying it to suit than fighting the OS/runtime...

Comment: one of the foundation libraries failed to run under 4.8, but it runs fine with 4.7.2

Answer (score 13):

.NET is part of Windows. New releases would appear as Windows updates in ARP (Control Panel -> Uninstall a Program -> View Installed Updates). To uninstall new .NET release, you would need to uninstall the correct Windows update.

Here are the update numbers for .NET 4.8 on Windows 10:

KB4486129 - for Windows 10 RS1/RS2 releases

KB4486153 - for Windows 10 RS3 and later releases

If uninstalling these updates does not fix the issue, I suggest opening a .NET issue on Developer Community web-site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/61/index.html) and provide .NET installation/uninstallation logs.

The tool, and instructions, for log collection is available at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12493

Comment: On 2012r2 it is KB4486105, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4486105/microsoft-net-framework-4-8-for-windows-rt-8-1-windows-8-1-and-windows

Answer (score 3):

In powershell:

```
wusa /uninstall /KB:4486153
```

And you can see the version number change before and after the command with this command:

```
(C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe -version)[4]
```

Comment: works perfect for me on Windows8, with the addition of the comment from the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57911569/1806239 it is KB4486105

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would have been just rolling back the OS to a date before you installed 4.8

The app is called System Restore.

n the Control Panel search box, type Recovery. Select Recovery > Open System Restore. In the Restore system files and setting box, select Next. Select the restore point that you want to use in the list of results