# Is it possible to get System.ValueTuple 4.5.0 onto a TFS 2015 server?

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild

In a WPF app I'm working on, I added a method that returns a tuple. Initially it didn't work. Researching why I learned that I had to add System.ValueTuple 4.5.0 NuGet package into the project. I did so, which resolved the issue. At least on my dev box.

However, it isn't building on our TFS 2015 build server. I had thought that including the NuGet package would handle any issues with System.ValueTuple during the build. The build server has .NET 4.5.2 on it. (Same as the VS project). I read on [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42867434/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-valuetuple) that downgrading System.ValueTuple to 4.3 would help to resolve the issue. I tried that, but it didn't work. TFS still gives errors indicating it doesn't understand the syntax of a tuple.

I'd like to ask then, is it possible to get System.ValueTuple 4.5.0 NuGet installed on the TFS build server?

If the answer to that question is no, or it doesn't make sense, then is the only option to install .NET 4.7.2 (or higher) on the build server?

Comment: You may want to tag this with `[msbuild]`.  It's more of an `msbuild` issue than a `tfs` issue (TFS is a lot of things)

Comment: Thank you, @Flydog57, good suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reference to this thread: [System.ValueTuple now supports .NET Framework 4.7](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fdotnet%2Fannouncements%2Fissues%2F25&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7Cfa18d953379e4a21687408d8c2894480%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637473242097950333%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=uY5g7m5Y6GLWnr5TbQJF5Bk8CmkUvy9oJj7%2BaAgg1Fc%3D&reserved=0), you need to install.NET 4.7.2 (or higher) on the Team Foundation Server 2015 build server. Also this [blog](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fvisualstudiomagazine.com%2Farticles%2F2015%2F06%2F29%2Fjuly-20-vs-2015-tfs-2015-net-4-6%25C2%25A0release.aspx&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7Cfa18d953379e4a21687408d8c2894480%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637473242097960324%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=p7LHd1RGMpyr0RNBx5VTD0Yk7TbRi7cwK5l451%2FrQUU%3D&reserved=0) mentioned TFS 2015 and .NET 4.6 were released at that time. So Team Foundation Server 2015 couldn't pre-install .NET 4.7.

In addition, [Team Foundation Server is now called Azure DevOps Server](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fserver%2Ftfs-is-now-azure-devops-server%3Fview%3Dazure-devops-2020&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7Cfa18d953379e4a21687408d8c2894480%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637473242097970321%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=VMXKRpGIQ3tvq7Ycgy720JX91mZH%2BY0JkKAHoTS9wwM%3D&reserved=0), you could consider to [upgrade your deployment to the latest version of Azure DevOps Server 2020](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fserver%2Fupgrade%2Fget-started%3Fview%3Dazure-devops-2020&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7Cfa18d953379e4a21687408d8c2894480%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637473242097970321%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=PenYqEm1lk9LrsUYlF8Jmph16ubhUWCzlPgfoM7Y6%2Fs%3D&reserved=0), and then can enjoy the latest service.

Comment: Thank you, Edward. I followed the links to https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download where it recommended I download .NET 4.8. However, that failed because it insisted on .NET 4.7.2. I got onto the build server to try to uninstall .NET 4.8. It doesn't show up in Programs and Features. How do I remove .NET 4.8, when it doesn't show up?

Comment: You could refer to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57601475/how-to-uninstall-net-framework-4-8-from-windows-10 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/troubleshoot-blocked-installations-and-uninstallations for guidance.